# Bind two or more withespaces gridview

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

Im trying to bind two or more whitespaces in gridview, but it only show one.

Example bind:

```
"|-----        -----|"
```

Result:

```
"|----- -----|"
```

Someone knows how to show the exactly value?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All spaces after the first one are ignored on HTML page. Try replacing them with `&nbsp;`. So if you have something like:

```
<%# Eval("Column1") %>
```

where `Column1` contains the `|-----        -----|` string, you might need this:

```
<%# ((string)Eval("Column1")).Replace(" ", "&nbsp;") %>
```